# Java CodeModel: annotation with class as value - class not on classpath

Tags: java, code-generation

I need to generate code and in this case annotations using suns CodeModel library. The annotations value is a Class object. However that class is not known at compile time. The solution I have now is:

```
JAnnotationUse oneToMany = field.annotate(OneToMany.class)
    .param("targetEntity", Class.forName(className);
```

However this obviously requires that the according class is on the classpath. I want to avoid the user having to deal with such issues.

Of course the other option would be to generate the java source code file and manipulate it afterwards (as pure string) but that seems very messy.

Is there any way with CodeModel to use the plain string className + ".class" instead?

Comment: Why not just `Class.forName()` as you already use for the argument?

Comment: because that requires the class to be loaded. And since it can be any class, there is no guarantee it is on the class path. This should be user friendly meaning the user should not require to understand how to add a jar to the class path and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Here my solution. Use javaassist to generate the class and the according Class object at runtime. Since the end result will be

```
 @OneToMany(targetEntity = com.foo.Bar.class)
```

as normal text in a java source code file, it does not matter that this generated "dummy class" is not actually equivalent to the real actual class that was referenced.

So we adjust the creation of the annotation as Guillaume indicated and catch the `ClassNotfoundExeption`. In the exception handler we call the `generateDummyClass` method that uses javaassist to create a Class object:

```
JAnnotationUse oneToMany = field.annotate(OneToMany.class);
//...snipped...
    try {
        oneToMany.param("targetEntity", Class.forName(jpaProperty.getTargetEntity()));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        try {
            Class targetEntityClass = generateDummyClass(jpaProperty.getTargetEntity());
            oneToMany.param("targetEntity", targetEntityClass);
        } catch (CannotCompileException compileEx) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Method `generateDummyClass` that create a class object at runtime using javaassist:

```
private Class<?> generateDummyClass(String fullQualifedClassName)
        throws IOException, CannotCompileException {

    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    pool.insertClassPath(new ClassClassPath(this.getClass()));
    CtClass ctClass = pool.makeClass(fullQualifedClassName);
    Class<?> clazz = ctClass.toClass();
    return clazz;
}
```

And we get a java source code file with:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = org.foo.Bar.class)
private Set<Bar> bars = new HashSet<Bar>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the case where the class it not in the classpath by catching the [ClassNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html):

```
try {
 JAnnotationUse oneToMany = field.annotate(OneToMany.class)
    .param("targetEntity", Class.forName(className);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
 // handle the exception
}
```

The part where you handle the exception really depends on what you're trying to achieve, depending on the situation you might want to log the error/add another anotation/throw an exception/...